# Trabajar con un método asincrónico en Volley (librería de Android)

Tags: java, android, android-volley, asincronismo

Estoy trabajando con *[Volley](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800)*, una librería de *Android*.

Tengo un método en el `ONCREATE` de mi clase, el problema es que como es asincrónico no llega a cargarse a tiempo y mi página continúa todo su proceso y a la primera vez de esto no tengo el valor visible. ¿Existe alguna forma elegante de hacer que la aplicación espere a que termine este método asincrónico para seguir con el resto del `oncreate`?

El método me trae un balance:

```
String rq = RequestManager.accountBalance(numeroTelefonico);
GenericController gC = new GenericController(true);
gC.accBalance(
    this, rq, new Response.Listener<AccountBalance>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(AccountBalance response) {

            if(response.getMessageRS().getErrorCode().compareTo("0")==0){
              String saldo = "";

                if(response.getMessageRS().getBalance().compareTo("")==0){
                  saldo =  response.getMessageRS().getAvailableBalance();
                }
                else{
                    saldo = response.getMessageRS().getBalance();
                }}
            else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: y donde deseas agregar el balance en un textview??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes implementado. Eso se suele hacer con un `ProgressDialog`, por eso hay en cada parte de la peiticón esto: `progressDialog.dismiss();`. Pero:

1. en el `onResponse` no debe ir dentro de un `else`, sino que en cuanto hay respuesta debes invocar `dismiss()`, para que se quite el diálogo, puesto que ya hay respuesta.
2. En el `onError` lo tienes bien.
3. Debes mostrarlo con  `progressDialog.show();` una vez hayas agregado la petición a la cola. En esa parte del código debes poner los nombres de tus variables reales para la cola de Volley, para la request que has creado.

Supongo que tienes el `ProgressDialog` declarado más arriba en tu código, más o menos así:

```
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TuActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");

  String rq = RequestManager.accountBalance(numeroTelefonico);
        GenericController gC = new GenericController(true);
        gC.accBalance(this, rq, new Response.Listener<AccountBalance>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(AccountBalance response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss(); //Debes quitarlo en cuanto haya respuesta
                if(response.getMessageRS().getErrorCode().compareTo("0")==0){
                            String saldo = "";

                            if(response.getMessageRS().getBalance().compareTo("")==0){
                                    saldo =  response.getMessageRS().getAvailableBalance();
                            }else{
                                    saldo = response.getMessageRS().getBalance();
                            }
                }else {
                    /*
                     *Este else puedes usarlo para otra cosa, 
                     *dependiendo de la lógica de tu programa
                     *pero no para el dismiss
                    */ 
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //En tu código tampoco se ve dónde añades la petición a la cola
        //Ahí debes mostrar el ProgressDialog

       requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest); //Aquí pon las variables requestQueue y jsArrayRequest como las hayas llamado en tu programa
       progressDialog.show();

}//LLave de cierre el onCreate
```

**P.D.:** La lógica que aplicas en el `onResponse` es un poco extraña. No me atreví a tocar ese bloque. Casi seguro que el último `else` sobra. Tampoco termino de ver la forma en que evalúas la respuesta que recibes... Creo que esa parte se podría mejorar, pero depende de qué tipo de respuesta es la que esperas en la petición.

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que yo en este mismo lugar , mando las solicitudes de aceptar permisos en la aplicacion y eso como que me cancela todo , porque aparece como superposicion de pantallas